# How to fix: Content-Type value is converted to lowercase

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to set content-type with lowercase and uppercase letters.

I tried to set the content-type with `res.set('Content-Type', 'UPPERCASE-CONTENT-TYPE');` and also with `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'UPPERCASE-CONTENT-TYPE');`. But the response I receive is then written in lower case: 'uppercase-content-type'.

Is there a way to set the value without it being written in lower case?

Comment: see there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665540/nodejs-not-retaining-upper-case-of-request-header

Comment: MIME types are case-insensitive and are written in lower-case by convention. Why do you want to break with convention?